# having issue with scrolling on iOS with jquery mobile

Tags: iphone, html, ios, css

PLease see the image below

[image]

As you can see in the image. `This area is empty`. The content area is not shown until the bottom of the screen. The bottom area remains empty with my css solution for ios. Please code below

css

```
    .ui-content {
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    div#container {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    div[data-role="header"] {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    div[data-role="content"] {
        position: absolute;
        top: 42px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .scrollable {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }

    .scrollable > * {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    }
```

here is my html

```
<div id="container">
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Net bank codes</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

       <div data-role="content" id="contents" class="scrollable">
      <ul id="codesContainer"></ul>
       </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</div>
```

**Why the bottom area remains empty and how can I fix so that the contents displays until the bottom of the screen?**

Comment: Are there any JavaScript flavor added to your HTML/CSS?

Comment: I haven't use javascript to solve this solution.

Comment: not yet. I gave up on this.